# Need a formula to calculate roll

Tags: javascript, php, hash, formula

Here is a script that gets the roll number (used in CSGODOUBLE):

```php
$server_seed = "39b7d32fcb743c244c569a56d6de4dc27577d6277d6cf155bdcba6d05befcb34";
$lotto = "0422262831";
$round_id = "1";
$hash = hash("sha256",$server_seed."-".$lotto."-".$round_id);
$roll = hexdec(substr($hash,0,8)) % 15;
echo "Round $round_id = $roll";
```

This rolls a number from 0 to 14. It is same every time, until the hash is changed.

I need to roll **5** numbers from **0 to 4** but they MUST NOT repeat. I need to do it with the same hash system.

**Example**:

```
$hash = "FIRST";
Outcomes:0,3,1,2,4;

$hash = "SECOND";
Outcomes:1,4,2,3,0;

$hash = "THIRD";
Outcomes:2,0,1,3,4

// etc.
```

Also, it would be perfect to get the formula in JavaScript, but PHP one works too.

Comment: I actually haven't tried anything yet, just looking for suggestions..

Comment: sorry but your question will likely be closed out.  StackOverflow is a tool for troubleshooting code, not tutorials.

Comment: ahh I understand, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `Array.prototype.slice()` to copy an original array of items, `Array.prototype.splice()` to retrieve an item from copied array, `Math.floor()`, `Math.random()` , `while` loop

```js
var arr = [0,1,2,3,4];
var res = [];
var copy = arr.slice(0);
while (copy.length) {
  res.push(copy.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * copy.length), 1)[0]);
}
document.write(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var arr = [0,1,2,3,4];
var res = [];
var copy = arr.slice(0);
while (copy.length) {
  res.push(copy.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * copy.length), 1)[0]);
}
document.write(res)
```

Comment: Some line of explanation added to your code snippet would make your answer a better one.